# keyPressed event with key hold

Tags: java, swing

I have this game, shooter (2 player game connected by datagram socket), and it has a ship.

I have a paint component to paint the ship.

**up** and **down** keys for movement of **p2**

**w** and **s** keys for movement of **p1**

When up key is **pressed**:

```
public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ){
    switch( e.getKeyCode() ){

        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: sendData("up start"); break;
```

my (ex.) **host** performs `sendData("up start")` which sends the said string to the **client** and when the client receives this, it performs `shoot.p1.moveUP();` which moves the **p1** ship on the another client **1 pixel up.**

When I move **p2** ship on (ex.) **host** (**press** up key once), the p2 ship on **client** moved 1 pixel.

(yes, every time I press the up button on host, client p2 moves 1 pixel)

But when I **prolong** the press of the key (**hold** up key), still, it moves just 1 pixel even though the painted ship on the host is moving as long as I hold the key.

How can I perform `sendData("up start")` when a key is being hold? I think `keyPressed` just performs it once unlike when it is in a `paintComponent` which is done as long as you are **pressing** the key.

I would like this to be solved without using any external libraries.. thanks :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with painting or datagrams. It's just a key listener question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWJGL has a Keyboard class you could use...

`import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;`

you can use a method `Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP);` to get the state of buttons, and then call a method that sends data, updates the game state, etc.

Comment: Is there no other way to solve this without using lwjgl?